# Numpy not solving matrix equation correctly

Tags: python, numpy

In the code below, Is `result` not supposed to be the same as `eqtn_ans[1]` since numpy had no problem solving the simultaneous equation? Or I'm I missing something?

Since numpy was able to get the inverse of `eqtn_coeffs` doesn't that make the equation solvable?

```
import numpy as np

def solve_simultaneous_equation(eq_coef, ans):
        A = np.array(eq_coef)
        B = np.array(ans)
        E = np.linalg.solve(A,B)
        return E

eqtn_coeffs = [[0.13230431079864502, -0.4504314661026001, 0.6201357841491699], 
               [-0.04826474189758301, -0.4006437063217163, 1.5354962348937988], 
               [-0.22883379459381104, -0.3508559465408325, 2.4508566856384277]]

eqtn_ans = [0.0, 0.7853981852531433, 1.3258177042007446]

params = solve_simultaneous_equation(eqtn_coeffs, eqtn_ans)

result = np.dot(eqtn_coeffs[1],params)

print(result) # The result of this should be the same as eqtn_ans[1] 
              # but its not even though numpy was able to solve the equation.
```

result:

```
0.625
```

Comment: I see a print statement, but no results.

Comment: Sorry, the print statement is the result. I will edit it now.

Comment: your `params` are [3.27075180e+15 1.72019082e+15 5.51642915e+14]. Might be ill-conditioned system

Comment: How do you conclude that `eqtn_ans` has any relation to a solution of that matrix?  Have you even tried to check that by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to see why you have a problem

```
np.linalg.det(eqtn_coeffs)
```

prints

```
3.3194268620340867e-17
```

If the determinant of a matrix is zero, then the linear system of equations it represents has no solution (to be mor precise, no desired unique solution). In other words, the system of equations contains at least two equations that are not linearly independent.

Comment: Why didn't numpy throw this error as it alway does when it is impossible to solve an equation? `numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix`

Comment: @Emmanuel good question, perhaps threshold to set the error is just a bit below determinant? So it passes the check but still really very close to 0, so no unique solution

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've hit the quantization limit of an IEEE-754 double. `params` comes out to

```
[3.27075180e+15, 1.72019082e+15, 5.51642915e+14]
```

Each value of `eqtn_coeffs` is ~1. The differences between them are *approximately* zero. In fact, you see a number that is ~ULP multiplied by 1e-15.

The rest of `eqtn_coeffs.dot(params)` shows the same pattern. Notice the approximately correct proportions rounded to very small multiples of the nearest powers of two:

```
[0.125 0.75  1.25 ]
```

A simpler way to describe this is to say that your equations are poorly conditioned. They are not technically dependent in a mathematical sense, but may as well be to the precision available on your machine, hence the obscenely large parameters.

Comment: What do you mean by ~1?

Comment: Approximately one